# Discord.py Join/Leave expect when Kicked/Banned

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have been trying to learn through searching websites to see how you can make it so that if a member of a server gets kicked it won't send a on_member_leave message that I have added. And so far I've found nothing on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen there is no on_member_leave in the discord.py rewrite.

I believe what you are looking for is discord.on_member_remove.
It is a client event that is called when a member leaves a guild

---

[Discord.py rewrite docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove)

> discord.on_member_join(member)
>
> discord.on_member_remove(member)
>
> Called when a Member leaves or joins a Guild.
>
> Parameters
>
> member (Member) – The member who joined or left.